# Redirect from directory and subdomain to root and retain Google links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

When the user enters these urls

1. example.com/subdir/whatever
2. subdomain.example.com/whatever

I want to serve these urls and show these urls in the address bar

1. example.com/whatever
2. example.com/subdomain/whatever

Essentially redirecting the pages at the old locations to the same pages at the new locations and thus retaining many thousands of google listings.

I have this for 1, but it's just redirecting everything to the home page:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302]
```

I have this for 2 and it isn't working at all.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdomain/$1 [R=302]
```

In the case of the latter, I am not entirely sure if I should kill the subdomain or not?

This is an amalgamation of two wordpress sites, one previously installed in a subdirectory and the other at a subdomain, so there are also WP rules in the .htaccess.

I am aware of the procedure for relocating a WP install, and that isn't the issue.

Comment: To be more precise, can you phrase your request as: When user enters this in browser address bar: `https://example.com/something/anyhting` I want to serve her this page `http://foo.example.com/this/that`,  and to show (`initial` or the `new URL`) in his address bar?

Comment: Apologies. I was trying to make it as clear as I could, but will keep this in mind.

Comment: No need to apologize :), it's just that with url rewrites the hardest part is to figure out what user really wants/needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rules :

```
# redirect subdomain to /example.com/subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdomain/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
# redirect www.domain/subdir/foo to /example.com/foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's sorted the directory urls, but not the subdomain ones. I am still not sure whether to make this work I need to delete the subdomain, or keep it?

Comment: When you enter `http://www.example.com/subdomain/whatever` in address bar, do you get the correct page?

Comment: It's working now. There was another redirect set up on the server that I was not aware of. Deleted it and it's all good now. Thanks.